# When i use ref to nuxt-link, i can't change styles on it (Nuxt.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, routerlink, nuxt-link

In my function I am using ref, which is binded to link, and when I try to change color (`ref.style.color = 'red'`), I see a error. Because ref which is binded to nuxt-link is Object, and it hasn't style property. I know that I can use the tag `<a></a>`, but does someone has ideas how can i make it with `nuxt-link`?

More info:
I have a link

```
<nuxt-link
    ref="card"
    @mousemove.native="move"
    @mouseleave.native="leave"
    @mouseover.native="over">

    Click

</nuxt-link>
```

In my function i want to change link position, useng transform.

```
move () {
      const card = this.$refs.card
      card.style.transform = `perspective(500px)`
    }
```

End i get this message in console

`TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'transform')`

Comment: Totally not clear. Please reformulate your question into something more understandable with a decent [repro] or some context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By selecting `nuxt-link` using `$refs` will only return Vue Component instead of node element due to `nuxt-link` is a component in Nuxt.js.

The correct way to selecting node element is using `$el`.

Answer referred from [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70380236/10353124).

Example:

```
const card = this.$refs.card.$el
card.style.transform = `perspective(500px)`
```

**To be mentioned**, I'm not sure what you trying to achieve but assuming you want to modify the style of an element in Vue way, you are supposed to use `:style="theElementStyles"` then only you update the element style with `this.theElementStyles = { transform: 'perspective(500px)' }`.

More details about inline style binding can check on **[Vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Binding-Inline-Styles)**.

Comment: OP never answered so eh, unlucky for good practices.